# Counting Key, Value Frequency in Column of Dictionaries Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Here is my dataframe:

```
Day      Hour         Dictionary
2.0       11.0         {2: [10, 11, 12, 13]} 
5.0       14.0         {6: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]} 
1.0       16.0         {1: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]} 
2.0       13.0         {2: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]} 
5.0       11.0         {5: [12, 12]}
```

The "Day" column comprise of the keys found within the "Dictionary" column, while the "Hour" column comprises of all the values. I want to count the frequency of times each pair of Day, Hour combinations appears within the entire "Dictionary" column. For instance, taking the first row; I want to count the number of times that 2.0 is a key within the "Dictionary" column, and when 2.0 is a key, how many times is 11.0 one of the values? Trying to figure out how to do this in Python.

Desired output would be a dataframe with the Day and Hour columns the same, but a final column with the frequency of their occurrences. Desired output would look something like this:

```
Day      Hour         Frequency
2.0       11.0         2
5.0       14.0         8 
1.0       16.0         11 
2.0       13.0         16 
5.0       11.0         8
```

In which the Day & Hour columns revert to the original dataframe, and the "Frequency" column shows how many times the "Day" observation is a key, and how many times the "Hour" column is included in the values when the respective Day is  a key. For instance, the above dataframe would mean that 2.0, 11.0 are a key, value pair 11 times in the original "Dictionary" column from the first dataframe.

Comment: Can you post a desired output?

Comment: Please post reproducible data. Also the specific desired output: do you want a dataframe? table? dict?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As other said please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where are those frequencies coming from?  How are those values selected?

Comment: Desired output would be another dataframe with the frequency of key, value pairs.

Comment: I think I understand, but for the first row, 11 doesn't show up in the list 2 times, it shows up only once

Comment: The frequencies are coming from the entire "Dictionary" column in the first dataframe. This issue might be solved if I could combine the "Dictionary" column to one big dictionary, but since each value is stored in the form of a string, I am having trouble converting the column into one larger dictionary

Comment: 11 only shows up once in the first row. But I want to count how many times the key value pair of 2, 11 shows up within the entire "Dictionary" column, not just that rows observation